# setting up a quiz in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is there a guide to setting up a multiple choice quiz in sharepoint online? i would want to set up a quiz which will email the result at the end to a couple of email addresses from an existing list item if this is possible?

thanks

Comment: Consider using MS Form since you are on Office 365

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the SharePoint 2013 platform there is the option to add a survey app to your site.

This will prompt you to create multiple choice questions which can be answered with either radio buttons, check boxes etc.

In order to create a survey:

1. Go to site contents
2. Click add an app
3. Find Survey and add to your site
4. Find the survey in your site contents. It will have a "new" symbol next to it if you have lots of apps already in your site.
5. You can now edit your survey and add more questions.

As an added bonus a survey can display a graphical representation of results.

As for creating one from an existing list I am not sure how you would go about this aside from either creating a new "quiz!" list with multiple choices fields or adding some multiple choice questions to the existing list and hiding the previous fields from users so that they only see the quiz questions.

Alerts can be set up on your list or survey for a choice of timings, either every time a new item changes or is added, or a daily, weekly summary etc. of the activity. These will be sent to a provided email address.

Hope this helps!

Cheers